# Command Prompt Shutdown Command

Tags: windows-7, command-line, shutdown

### Setup

I am running a Windows 7 PC and a Windows 7 Laptop both connected to a router forming a LAN. So, I want to remotely shutdown the laptop from the PC. I found out I could do this in [command prompt](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770416.aspx) by entering: `shutdown -i` or `shutdown/i`.  I then clicked "add" in the GUI that appeared and typed in the IP address of the laptop.

### Problem

However, it did not work but gave me this error:

```
The entered computer name is not valid or remote shutdown is not supported on the target computer. Check the name and then tryp again or contact your system administrator.<53>
```

I enabled and started the Remote Registry on both computers and it still did not work. I am an admin user on both computers are am logged into the desktop with an admin account. Any ideas?

Comment: Remote registry won't have an effect (it's only used to log shutdown event tracking)... also, when running a remote command you need to run the command as the admin user on the remote PC... for example: You're on PC A and you want to shutdown PC B... you need to run the command from A but give the PC B credentials... Finally: This MS page shows you the shutdown command: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc770416.aspx

Comment: How would I do that? I don't have to enter credentials for either the way I am doing it so far.

Comment: This answer may also help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526627/windows-7-remote-shutdown-access-denied5 - you could also try installing PsTools on your local computer. You can then run `cmd` on the other computer as the remote admin user

Comment: If you need to authenticate to the other machine first: `net use \\laptopname /user:username password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a domain account which has admin permissions on both computers? If so the following command from computer1 will work on computer2:
shutdown /m computer2 /s /t 00

You may want to check if the firewall is running on the second computer and verify the necessary exceptions are in place:

"To shut down or restart a remote computer, the Remote Administration and Windows Management Instrumentation firewall exceptions must be enabled on the remote computer."

Answer (score -1):

When I want to shutdown a computer I open a command prompt on the remote and then type in

```
shutdown /s /t 10
```

That command will shutdown the computer in 10 seconds 
here are the command switches for the shutdown command

```
To shutdown your PC type : shutdown / s

To restart your PC type : shutdown / r

To logoff your PC type : shutdown / l

The list of shutdown options include:

No args        Display help. This is the same as typing /?.
/?              Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
/i              Display the graphical user interface (GUI).  This must be the first option.
/l              Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.
/s             Shutdown the computer.
/r             Full shutdown and restart the computer.
/g             Full shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is rebooted, restart any registered applications.
/a              Abort a system shutdown.  This can only be used during the time-out period.
/p             Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning. Can be used with /d and /f options.
/h             Hibernate the local computer. Can be used with the /f option.
/hybrid    Performs a shutdown of the computer and prepares it for fast startup. Must be used with /s option.
/e              Document the reason for an unexpected shutdown of a computer.
/o             Go to the advanced boot options menu and restart the computer.
/t xxx      Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds. The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
/c             Comment on the reason for the restart or shutdown. Maximum of 512 characters allowed.
/f             Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
/d            Provide the reason for the restart or shutdown.
```

Comment: I want to do it from a remote computer not the same computer.